# custom setter method does not work (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to define a method inside the constructor to modify the 'name' attribute (but it doesn't seem to work).I can't figure out what's wrong with my code(I'm newbie). Thanks in advance.

```
function Animal(){
  this.name=""
  this.setName=function(name){
    this.name=name
  }
}
var myDog=new Animal()
myDog.setName="Max"
console.log(myDog.name)//" "
console.log(myDog.setName)//"Max"
```

Comment: You are not using the method. You are overwriting the `.setName` property. `myDog.setName('Max')`, is how you should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setName` is function so change your code to `myDog.setName("Max")`

```js
function Animal(){
  this.name=""
  this.setName=function(name){
    this.name=name
  }
}
var myDog=new Animal()
myDog.setName("Max")
console.log(myDog.name)
//console.log(myDog.setName)//"Max"
```